# Equivalent function to IO.Path.GetFileName for urls?

Tags: .net, url

In .NET 4.0, whats the equivalent function to `IO.Path.GetFileName` for urls?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class is your friend.

> Provides an object representation of a uniform resource identifier (URI) and easy access to the parts of the URI.

`IsFile` will try to determine if the `Uri` does indeed point to a file.

Use the `Segements` property in order to get the file name (it will be the last segment).

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com/title/index.htm");
var filename = uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length - 1];
// filename == "index.htm"
```

Comment: Thanks / works well, except that isFile gives me false on this uristring: [link](http://www.example.com/foo/bar/banner/enu_wide_small_219x113_white.gif)

Comment: isFile will only return true if the url is of the form file://

Answer (score 2):

You may stick to creating Uri object or if you care about performance use something similar to this one:

```
    public class UriHelpers
    {
        public static string GetFileNameFromUrl(string url)
        {
            string lastSegment = url.Split('/').Last();

            return lastSegment.Substring(0, lastSegment.IndexOf('?') < 0 ? lastSegment.Length : lastSegment.IndexOf('?'));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Server.MapPath() to map a physical path from a virtual path.

Additionally, there are a number of methods within the [HTTPUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90d18ktz.aspx) that will help you map various different types of path.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, the main being described [here](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/317977-extract-filename-url)
Baqsically exploiting the Uri class, and maybe string tokeniztion if needed.