# remove before specific word in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, textbox

how to remove texts up to one word in textbox ?

Example :

```
Textbox.text = "http://google.com/text/word"
```

i want to have just **WORD**  in that textbox .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518990/equivalent-function-to-io-path-getfilename-for-urls)

```
Dim uri = New Uri("http://google.com/text/word")
Dim word = uri.Segments(uri.Segments.Length - 1)
Textbox.text = word
```

Comment: i get this error : Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'String'.