# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException occurred in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to extract the name of the file from a url in C#

The code I have used is as follows:

```
string url = "https://something.something.something/something/filename.abc");
// the filename in this case should be filename.abc

int firstIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/');
int length = url.Length - url.lastIndexOf('/');
string filename = url.Substring(firstIndex, length);
Console.WriteLine("The name of the file is : " + filename);
```

However, this prints the following:
The name of the file is : /filename.abc

I would like to get the filename as filename.abc
So I did this

```
int firstIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
// All the other code remains the same, and this is when the visual studio throws this error
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

How do I solve this?

Comment: You forgot to decrement the length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var fileName = "https://something.something.something/something/filename.abc";
var f = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
```

Or (via [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519029/125740))

```
var uri = new Uri("https://something.something.something/something/filename.abc");
var f = uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length - 1];
```

Comment: Works well. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do this to get the file name.

```
var fileName = "https://something.something.something/something/filename.abc".
Split('/').Last();
```

Comment: This will generate quite a few temporary strings

Comment: Maybe, but that may not be a problem either.

Answer (score 0):

Your length parameter is the length from the beginning to the last /. That is not going to work. You could try:

```
var file = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/"));
```

Comment: This will not generate the correct filename. This would generate something like: /filename.abc

Comment: You are right, should have had url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/")+1);

Answer (score 0):

You need to decrement the `length` variable as well:

```
int firstIndex = url.LastIndexOf('/') +1;
int length = url.Length - url.LastIndexOf('/')-1;
```

Or use the [Substring(int)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx) override that only accepts a starting parameter and reads everything from the starting point to the end:

```
string filename = url.Substring(firstIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this-

```
using System.IO;

string url = "https://something.something.something/something/filename.abc";
string filename = Path.GetFileName(url);
Console.WriteLine("The name of the file is : " + filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

By increasing firstIndex by 1 without adjusting the length variable by -1, you slid your substring window past the end of the string.

Add a - 1 to the end of your third line of code.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the filename with the extension and without the preceding  slash:

```
var filename = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```